# How is this Docker volume's route mapped in my host machine?

Tags: macos, docker-compose, docker-volume

In my `docker-compose.yml` file, I have this container definition:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:2.3.5
  volumes:
    - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
```

I cannot find `elasticsearch` data because I don't know where is `esdata` located. How is it mapped in my host machine? Where is that directory? I'm running it on a MacOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mapping is HOST:CONTAINER

If your volume works, the esdata directory is in the same directory as your docker-compose file.

In my docker-compose file I write "./:/exemple/of/route"

You can check volumes with a `docker inspect [container name]`

You can also do this `find / -type d -name 'esdata'` to find the directory on your host

Comment: I run `docker inspect` and I found out the route. Volume is not being mounted in the same dir as docker compose file because the route hasn't the dot slash (`./`) so the system is mounting it in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/esdata`. Thanks, you solved my problem. (`find` command works in MacOS, too, btw)

Comment: You should also know that docker named volumes are diferent and offer more options(your docker-compose file) than the solution from this answer that is just host mapping directory